# edgelet_utils... Get https://warlibregistry.azurecr.io/v2/iot-edge-engine-simulator/manifests/0.0.1-amd64: unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I get a quite strange error message after executing Install-SecurityDaemon.
I deployed the IoT Edge module image to Azure Registry using Visual Studio Code. Then, I try to execute the IoT Edge solution in the simulator. Everything is ok.

I executed Install-SecurityDaemon. Everything went ok. But when I exec "iotedge list" command, I saw that only two main modules arrived but there is no module developed by me
`PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> iotedge list
NAME             STATUS           DESCRIPTION               CONFIG
edgeHub          failed           Failed (137) an hour ago  mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0
edgeAgent        running          Up 1 second               mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0`

I'd seen the log and found only one error message:

`11.11.2018 22:52:37 warn: edgelet_docker::runtime -- Attempt to pull image failed.
11.11.2018 22:52:42 info: edgelet_core::watchdog -- Checking edge runtime status
11.11.2018 22:52:42 info: edgelet_core::watchdog -- Edge runtime is running.
11.11.2018 22:52:43 warn: edgelet_docker::runtime -- Attempt to pull image failed.
11.11.2018 22:52:43 info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-11-11 19:52:43.487711600 UTC] "POST /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error 141 "-" "-" pid(any)
11.11.2018 22:52:43 warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Get https://warlibregistry.azurecr.io/v2/iot-edge-engine-simulator/manifests/0.0.1-amd64: unauthorized: authentication required
11.11.2018 22:52:55 info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-11-11 19:52:55.502141500 UTC] "POST /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error 141 "-" "-" pid(any)
11.11.2018 22:52:55 warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Get https://warlibregistry.azurecr.io/v2/iot-edge-engine-simulator/manifests/0.0.1-amd64: unauthorized: authentication required`

Then I execute "docker login" command to be sure, that docker properly authorized in Azure registry. Everything was ok. Then, I reinstall SecurityDaemon. I got the same error.

Executing command

`PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker pull warlibregistry.azurecr.io/iot-edge-engine-simulator:0.0.1-amd64
0.0.1-amd64: Pulling from iot-edge-engine-simulator
Digest: sha256:4ba6ae6442ca974b2c52459b85c0861e9664f26990c6e87f20829954f4d67d09`

`Status: Image is up to date for warlibregistry.azurecr.io/iot-edge-engine-simulator:0.0.1-amd64`

return no errors. But if try to get manifest https://warlibregistry.azurecr.io/v2/iot-edge-engine-simulator/manifests/0.0.1-amd64 I really got the JSON with the error "unauthorized: authentication required".

In the Azure Portal after adding my module engineSimulator I saw another one iot_edge_engine_simulator with type "Module identity" which is not created by me. When I installed e.g. Microsoft module termoSensor - there is no such additional module.

So, I'm stuck, I don't know why the error occurs and what to do further.

Thank you for a help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. When I set the module I missed filling "Container Registry Settings". In the case of using your own container registry (not Microsoft), you MUST fill authorization parameters.

In my case: 
NAME: WarlibRegistry
ADDRESS: warlibregistry.azurecr.io
USERNAME & PASSWORD from the "Access keys" section of your container registry.